# Nginx + Varnish Issues

Tags: nginx, varnish

Hi all i have created this config for using Nginx and Varnish cache but i see that its not working as expected, its added on conf.d and Nginx request also sites-enabled (default config)
please can anyone give me any hint how can i do this config? im tring to use this scheme:

Nninx: 443 -> Varnish: 6081 -> Nginx: 81 -> PHP: 9000

```
server {

    listen 443;

    #server_name  tirana.com;
    
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header HTTPS "on";
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
       deny all;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
       allow all;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/tirana_com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/torana.com.key;

}

server {

    listen 80;

    server_name tirana.com;

    #return 301 https://tirana.com$request_uri;
    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;

}

server {

    listen 81;

    #server_name tirana.com;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php index.html;

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/access1.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/error1.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        #try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~\.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe what exactly is not working as expected. Is there an error? Are you seeing the wrong output? Do you have logs that show the issue?

Comment: The issue that im facing, the first is when i stop varnish its supposed to not access the wordpress because the cache is down, still i access the web page, second its not displaying on header the varnish signature

Comment: Also i get  error : tirana.com didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE whien i delete all the configs and i try only this one that i have posted

Comment: Also with reviewed configuration i get bad gateway. on nginx logs i get failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:

Comment: Please add the output from `sudo systemctl cat varnish` to your question. Please also check if the `Connection refused` error comes from port 443 connecting to port 6081, or if the error comes from port 80 connecting to the PHP socket.

Comment: Hello this is the varnish config # /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service
[Unit]
Description=Varnish HTTP accelerator
Documentation=https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/6.1/ man:varnishd

[Service]
Type=simple
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitMEMLOCK=82000
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
ExecReload=/usr/share/varnish/varnishreload
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
PrivateTmp=true
PrivateDevices=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Answer (score 1):

While your configuration files look good, the fact that you're now seeing an `X-Varnish` header in your response would indicated that Varnish isn't used.

Also, you mention that when you stop Varnish, the website still works to some extent.

We need to take this one step by step.

## 1. Stop the services

We should first stop all services to ensure that everything is down

```bash
sudo systemctl stop nginx
sudo systemctl stop varnish
sudo systemctl stop php-fpm
```

## 2. Fire up Varnish

Call `sudo systemctl start varnish` to start Varnish.

Then make sure you run `sudo varnishlog -g request` on a separate shell and keep that command open.

Next up on your SSH shell for that server, run `curl -I localhost:6081` to send a request to Varnish.

Because Nginx is down, Varnish should return an `HTTP 503` error and some output should appear in the shell that has the `varnishlog` command running.

Check your `default.vcl` file and make sure your backend definition points to port `81`.

> If this is not the case, Varnish isn't properly working and you need to debug your Varnish configuration.

## 3. Start PHP

Run `sudo systemctl start php-fpm` to start up the PHP-FPM service. In your description you mentioned port `9000`, which is the standard PHP-FPM port.

However, in your Nginx config, you're connecting with PHP using the `/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock` UNIX domain socket.

Check your PHP-FPM pool configuration to see if you're using TCP/IP or UDS. That might explain the gateway error.

## 3. Start Nginx

Run `sudo systemctl start nginx` to fire up the webserver (and TLS proxy).

Run `curl -I localhost:81` on the server and check the output.

You should get PHP working first before you start looking at Varnish.

If that doesn't return the right output yet, focus on these configurations.

## 4. Test the chain of services

Make sure `sudo varnishlog -g request` is still open. Run `curl -k -I https://localhost` to send an HTTPS request to the Nginx vhost that handles the TLS termination.

Check `/var/log/nginx/access.log` and see if there's an entry that corresponds with the HTTPS request you just sent. Also check `/var/log/nginx/error.log` for possible messages.

Meanwhile, check the output of `varnishlog`. If there's not matching log output there, Varnish is obviously not properly connected to the `443` Nginx vhost.

Varnishlog can also give you information about the connection between Varnish and Nginx on port `81`. This should help you understand what's going on.

## 5. Share the logs

If you're not finding the solution, but you have useful log output, please add it to your original question, I'll help you figure out what's going on.

When sharing log output, please make sure you use the code block syntax so it's easily readable. Please also provide context for the logs, so we understand what part of the chain it represents and under which circumstances the HTTP request was triggered.